# Forcing the context

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

I have this class where I have a private property and a public method for access:

```
Person = function () {
    this.Name = "asd";

    var _public = new Object();
    _public.Name = function (value) {
        if (value == undefined) { //Get
            return this.Name
        } else {
            this.Name = value; //Set
        }
    };

    return _public;
};
```

I want to force the context in `_public.Name` for access a `this.Name`.

I know the technique of closure, but I want to see if I can force a context.

I found a technique to do it, extend object Function:

```
Function.prototype.setScope = function (scope) {
    var f = this;

    return function () {
        f().apply(scope);
    }
}
```

And my class becomes:

```
Person = function () {
    this.Name = "asd";

    var _public = new Object();
    _public.Name = function (value) {
        if (value == undefined) {
            return this.Name
        } else {
            this.Name = value;
        }
    }.setScope(this);

    return _public;
};
```

So I can force correctly the context, but I can not pass `value` and can not, however, return `this.Name`.

Comment: So new Person() returns a closure on the bound to this _public.Name function. This is a rather complex way for creating a class that instead of return an object, returns a function. This is probably not what you are trying to do. But it is difficult to guess what you want to achieve from the code sample provided.

Comment: @Jean: *"This is a rather complex way for creating a class that instead of return an object, returns a function."* It doesn't return a function object, just an object. The object has a function assigned to its `Name` property. Agreed this is not how I'd do it, though.

Comment: ^^ you're right, it does return an object, but this is a rather convoluted way for doing something otherwise trivial.

Comment: @Ermes - a function's *this* keyword has nothing to do with scope, nor is it "context".

Comment: @RobG: "Context" is (for good or ill) the term mostly used for it, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not

```
f().apply(scope);
```

just

```
f.apply(scope);
```

(No `()` after `f`.) You want to use the `apply` function on the function `f` object, not *call* the function `f` and access `apply` on its return value.

To also pass on the arguments that your function in `setScope` receives, add this:

```
f.apply(scope, arguments);
```

`arguments` is an implicit argument to all functions, which is a pseudo-array of the actual arguments passed to the function at runtime. `apply` accepts any array-like thing as its second parameter to specify the arguments to use when calling the underlying function.

I'd also have it return the return value:

```
return f.apply(scope, arguments);
```

So `setScope` becomes:

```
Function.prototype.setScope = function (scope) {
    var f = this;

    return function () {
        return f.apply(scope, arguments);
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/aduyev/3)

Note that the usual name for this function, and the name it has in the new [ECMAScript5 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), is `bind` (Section 15.3.4.5; ECMAScript5's `bind` also lets you [curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) arguments, which isn't done by this implementation). `setScope` is a particularly unfortunate name, because it doesn't set the *scope*, it sets the *context*.

Having said all that, there's no reason you need `setScope` in your `Person` constructor. You can just do this:

```
Person = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.Name = "asd";

    var _public = new Object();
    _public.Name = function (value) {
        if (value == undefined) {
            return self.Name;
        } else {
            self.Name = value;
        }
    };

    return _public;
};
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/aduyev/4)

But using `bind` (aka `setScope`) can be useful in places where you don't want a new closure over the context in which you're doing it.

---

**Off-topic**: The way you're specifying `Person` will break certain things people might expect to work, such as:

```
var p = new Person();
alert(p instanceof Person); // Expect "true", but in your case will be "false"
```

...because you're replacing the object `new` created for you, but returning a different object out of your constructor (which overrides the default).

Rather than creating a new object and returning that in your constructor, allow the object constructed for you by `new` to be the object (and thus the `Person` relationship is maintained), but you can still get truly private variables and use accessors:

```
function Person() {
    // Private variable
    var name = "asd";

    // Accessor function
    this.Name = function(value) {
        if (typeof value === "undefined") {
            return name;
        }
        name = value;
    };
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/aduyev/6)

As you can see, this is dramatically simpler, and it preserves the `instanceof` relationship. Note that we're not qualifying our references to `name` within `Name` at all, and so we're using the local variable in the constructor call in which our `Name` function, which closes over it, was created.

I've also taken the liberty there of giving the constructor function a *name*, because [I'm not a fan of anonymous functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html). I should have given the accessor a name as well:

```
function Person() {
    // Private variable
    var name = "asd";

    // Accessor function
    this.Name = Person_Name;
    function Person_Name(value) {
        if (typeof value === "undefined") {
            return name;
        }
        name = value;
    }
}
```

---

**Off-topic 2**: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript code is to use initial caps on function names *only* for constructor functions (like `Person`), and not on other kinds of functions (like `Name`). You're free to do whatever you like, of course, but I thought I'd mention the convention, as it makes it easier for other people to read your code.

---

Worth noting: **All** of these techniques result in *every single `Person` object* having its *own* copy of the accessor function. If there are going to be a lot of these objects, that could be a memory issue. If there are only going to be a few, that's fine.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to remove after the last test

Comment: Thank you very much for your exhaustive explanation and for your time

Answer (score 1):

First thing, I think the correct way to go about this is the "closure" method, as the syntax is easier and simpler to understand and makes more sense and most object oriented code written in Javascript is written that way. Another thing to note is that in your method, the "private" member can be accessed from outside by accessing `Person.Name` (instead of `(new Person()).Name`).

That being said, it seems that you want something like [Prototype.JS's bind method](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind), which allows you to bind a function reference as a method call to a specific object, and also passes all the arguments correctly (including allowing preloaded arguments).

Look at Prototype.JS source for the complete implementation, but a simple implementation of this semantic might look like this:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(context) {
    var callee = this;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
    return function() {
        var newargs = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0));
        return callee.apply(context, newargs);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. But if I guess that you are trying to create a Person class with a name method to get/set the person's name, here is my suggestion:

```
function Person() {
  this._name = undefined; // not required but is better than assigning a fake name

  return this;
}

Person.prototype.name = function( _name ) {
  if ( _name === undefined ) return this._name; // get
  return this._name = _name; // set
}
```

Note that I have defined the name function with a lower case first letter. This is standard practice in JavaScript where only constructors are usually capitalized. To use this class you do:

```
person = new Person();

person.name( "Ermes Enea Colella" );

alert( person.name ); // displays "Ermes Enea Colella"
```

There is no need to bind any context with this method, so you may be looking for something else. If you can clarify your need, I'll be happy to edit my answer.

I hope this helps.