# Why can't prototype functions resolve 'this' in some cases?

Tags: javascript

Here's an example

```
function banana() {
    this.size = 5;

    this.say_size = function() {
        console.log(this.size);
    }.bind(this);
}

banana.prototype.say_size2 = function() {
    console.log(this.size);
}

var b = new banana();

b.say_size();
b.say_size2();        //TLDR: why does this line work without binding?

setTimeout(b.say_size, 100);
setTimeout(b.say_size2, 200);
```

So, in the case I call b.say_size or b.say_size2 directly, 'this' refers to the banana object and I get '5' as output on both.

In case the function is called by a timer or an event though, 'this' is set to window unless the called function is bound to the object.

What I don't understand is how say_size2 gets the right 'this' when called directly without the prototype function being bound to anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling a method on an object, (`b.say_size()` or `b.say_size2()`) context inside a method points to that object (`this === b`).

`setTimeout` accepts a function as a first argument, which is executed in global context (`this === window`).

For simplicity try to assign a function to a variable and call it:

```js
function banana() {
    this.size = 5;

    this.say_size = function() {
        console.log(this.size);
    //}.bind(this); Let's not bind yet
    }
}

banana.prototype.say_size2 = function() {
    console.log(this.size);
}

var b = new banana();

b.say_size(); // 5 even without binding, instance method
b.say_size2(); // 5, instance method from prototype chain

var foo = b.say_size2;
foo(); // undefined
var bar = b.say_size;
bar(); // undefined

bar = b.say_size.bind(b);
bar(); // 5
```

In both cases these functions are executed in a global context, however, as `b.say_size` was explicitly bound to a different object, JavaScript engine will not force `this` to be `window`.

#### Further reading

[Forcing the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671423/forcing-the-context)

[How does "this" keyword work within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-function)